# can abstract base class access its own abstract property in C#. If yes, then will the value be same as that of underlying child object?

Tags: c#, inheritance

can abstract base class access its own abstract property in C#. If yes, then will the value be same as that of underlying child object ??

```
abstract class A : IEquitable<A>
{
    abstract string Key {get; set;}

    Equal(A other) 
    {
        // in this part , I ma accessing the abstract property
        if(this.Key == other.Key) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

// Class B is inheriting class A
class B : A 
{
    // value is given to that abstract property in child class
    public override string Key { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you posted the code in your IDE instead of here you could already know the answer: yes it's possible and yes it's the child class' value, which other value could be there?

Comment: yeah agreed. Actually, I don't work on C#, and this came up in conversation where we were discussing how java doesn't allow abstract at variables. Intention was to find out if in C#, the abstract percolates to the set get property of the variable (which is what we will use in Java for abstraction) or on the variable value itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the concrete child class, **must** implement this property (since its only an abstract definition of the property on the abstract class). And both properties point always to the same data.

Consider this:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Key {get; set;}
}

class ChildA : Base 
{   
    //This one overrides the default adding extra/different logic
    public override string Key { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}

class ChildB : Base 
{   
    //This one adds a new property, making the other one no long accessable directly.
    public new string Key { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}

var a = new ChildA();
a.Key //Some Value
((Base)a).Key // Some Value
new ChildB();
b.Key //Some Value
((Base)b).Key // null
```

### Best practice

Beste practice on overriding variables or functions is to add logic, not to change or remove it.

eg: add an observer to check if property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract syntax of property is like syntax of auto property. But you can implement that as property with backing field or auto property or as computed property without backing field.

Abstract members dont have implementation. When a child class implement abstract members that value is for child class itself.

Another child of that class can be implemented in this way. And does not conflict with other childs.

```
public override string Key
{
    get { return ""; }
    set { /*do nothing*/}
}
```